# CakePHP Updating 2 Columns

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a '`Users`' table and I keep all account-related data there. It contains `id, username, password, status, removed, last_login`

By default, when an account is created, `status = 2` and `removed = 0`.

I have a function that denies an application. And when an admin denies an application, `status = 0` and `removed = 1`.

Now, my problem is that when I try to update these fields, I also noticed that my password field also updates.

Here's my code for the deny:

```
   public function deny(){

        $user_id = $this->request->params['pass'][0];

        if(!$user_id){
            $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid action!', 'alert_box', array('class' => 'alert-danger'), 'member'); 
            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'admin', 'action' => 'member'));
        }else if($user_id){
            $this->User->id = $user_id;

            if($this->User->save(array('User' => array('status' => 0,'removed' => 1)))){
                $this->Session->setFlash('Successfully denied the application of the selected applicant!', 'alert_box', array('class' => 'alert-success'), 'member'); 
            }else{
                $this->Session->setFlash('Failed to deny the application of the selected applicant!', 'alert_box', array('class' => 'alert-danger'), 'member'); 
            }
            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'admin', 'action'=>'member'));
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure why my password is changing too. But for more info, this is my User::beforeSave:

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password(
          $this->data['User']['password']
        );
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: `I'm not sure why my password is changing too` - your before save function unconditionally adds password to the data to be saved whether it's present in `$this->data` or not. Genuinely: is it not obvious what the consequences of doing that are for an unrelated save?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the callbacks option to false? This way the beforeSave function will not be executed.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-save-array-data-null-boolean-validate-true-array-fieldlist-array

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your beforeSave callback to this

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (isset($this->data['User']['password']) && $this->data['User']['password']) {
        $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);
    }

    return true;
}
```

so, hash the password only and only if it exists in the given array